# Best way to archive old contacts in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, contacts

I store my contacts in Outlook (Outlook 2010 with Exchange 2003). I have lots of contacts that are old and I don't use anymore, but I do not want to delete.

What is the best way to archive these old contacts?

Comment: Do you want to keep them in a form that only Outlook understands, or do you want them in a generic format that can be imported into other programs?

Comment: "only Outlook understands" is fine

Comment: CSV format is the most compatible format for address book archives, and its something you can actually open and read if needed.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to create new contact folder and named it something like "old contact data" etc. To create new contact list is as simple as creating new folder in Outlook, but you start with the primary contact folder and then right click and select "create new folder", name it and enter to confirm. Then you can move any old contact data or expired contact information and store or archive it into just created contact folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).